# ISAPI DLL fails to start thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, iis

I have an ISAPI extension DLL that uses a threaded helper object.  On my QA server the thread executes successfully, on the live server it does not.  Server hardware is the same on both environments. Development language is Delphi XE2.

```
unit uRemoteTest2Intf;

interface
uses Soap.InvokeRegistry, System.Types, Soap.XSBuiltIns;

type
  { Invokable interfaces must derive from IInvokable }
  IRemoteTest = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{9F4E3DF8-5D22-46FE-B3DC-B6CD8EE971AD}']
    function LogData(const Value: string): string; stdcall;
  end;

implementation

initialization
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(IRemoteTest));

end.

unit uRemoteTest2Impl;

interface
uses Soap.InvokeRegistry, System.Types, Soap.XSBuiltIns, uRemoteTest2Intf, uThread;

type
  { TRemoteTest }
  TRemoteTest = class(TInvokableClass, IRemoteTest)
  private
    worker: TWorkerThread;
  public
    function LogData(const Value: string): string; stdcall;
    constructor Create; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  uLog, Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages;

procedure RemoteTestFactory(out obj: TObject);
{$J+}
const
  iInstance: IRemoteTest = nil;
  instance: TRemoteTest = nil;
begin
  if instance = nil then
  begin
    instance := TRemoteTest.Create;
    instance.GetInterface(IRemoteTest, iInstance)
  end;
  obj := instance
end;

constructor TRemoteTest.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  //SetApplicationLogLevel(2);
  //SetApplicationLogFilename('c:\temp\test.txt');

  Log('Calling TRemoteTest.Create');
  worker := TWorkerThread.Create;
  worker.Start;
  if worker.Suspended then
    Log('worker is  suspended')
  else
    Log('worker is not suspended');

  Log('Called TRemoteTest.Create');
end;

destructor TRemoteTest.Destroy;
begin
  Log('Calling TRemoteTest.Destroy');
  worker.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TRemoteTest.LogData(const Value: string): string;
begin
  Log('Calling TRemoteTest.LogData');
end;

initialization

InvRegistry.RegisterInvokableClass(TRemoteTest, RemoteTestFactory);

end.

unit uThread;

interface
uses
  System.Classes;

type
  TWorkerThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  uLog;

constructor TWorkerThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(true);
  Log('Calling TWorkerThread.Create');
end;

destructor TWorkerThread.Destroy;
begin
  Log('Calling TWorkerThread.Destroy');
  inherited;
end;

procedure TWorkerThread.Execute;
begin
  NameThreadForDebugging('WorkerThread');
  Log('Executing Thread');
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    sleep(1000);
    Log('Executing thread');
  end;
  Log('Executed Thread');
end;

end.
```

{The Log procedure is an in house logging routine in the referenced uLog.pas file}

On the IIS server, the last piece if code to run is the TWorkerThread.Start (within the main thread). The thread's Execute method (which should opeartte within the context of that thread) never gets called.

Comment: Anything in the IIS or windows logs?

Comment: You need to provide more info about the issue. "It works on my QA server, on the live one it does not" is not near enough info. If you can't provide more, insert some logging or use the debugger to figure out where the issue might be, so you have more info we can use to try and help.

Comment: Thx Ken.  I've removed the logging calls in the code posted.  The first line in the thread's Execute method is a logging call, which never gets called.  
The logging code in the thread constructor is called.  The logging code in the thread's destructor is called when I recycle the IIS apoplication pool (but not before). My hunch is there is some lifetime or permissions setting on IIS ?

Comment: Hi Preet, nothin in either :(

Comment: I've simplified the code, to just create a simple worker thread that is spawned from the main Request handler.

Comment: I've finally got back to this problem.  If I change the account that the IIS application pool runs under, then the thread executes.  If I leave it as ApplicationPoolIdentity it does not execute. So it appears to be a permission issue, but I'm not sure what the solution is.